# Photodetector and low noise amplifier acting as low pass filter

Tags: amplifier, impedance, photodiode, low-noise-amplifier

I need some basic advice for impedance matching: I have a photodetector (Det01CFC from Thorlabs, https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/275cb418cdc2cf1f-A2E46103-D9C0-3581-4553E3D3CA93AD83/DET01CFC-Manual.pdf) that generates a current. For my experiment, I would like to amplify this signal with an amplifier to subsequently read it out with a digital oscilloscope.

The amplifier that I use is the LNA-1440 (https://rfbayinc.com/products_pdf/product_88.pdf) with an input impedance of 50 Ohm. Since the input impedance of the amplifier matches the source impedance of the photodetector, I connected them directly with an SMA-cable.

The problem that I am facing right now is that the signal gets attenuated for frequencies larger than a few MHz, i.e. it seems as if my circuit acts as a low pass filter. Do you have an idea why this could be the case?

Thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: How do you know that it isn't your driven light source that has the problem?

Comment: How are you measuring bandwidth?  Are you using a 50 ohm oscilloscope?  I suspect you are missing something.

Comment: The issue is that if I add a parallel resistor of 50 Ohm between the photodetector and the amplifier, I do not observe this attenuation anymore.

Comment: Yes, I measure with a 50 Ohm oscilloscope - I also suspect that something is missing, but I cannot spot it right now...

Comment: I realized that when I use a 50 Ohm parallel resistor between the amplifier and the photodetector, the attenuation of the signal is no longer observable on the oscilloscope.

One possibility of how I could understand this is that due to the photodetector, there is a capacitance parallel to the load resistance of the oscilloscope. Since those two act as a low-pass filter, I could see this attenuation. By adding a parallel resistance between the photodetector and the amplifier, however, this "low pass filter effect" gets reduced. What do you think? :)